Why is a basic (not acidic) electrolyte frequently suggested for electrolytic de-rusting of metal or iron objects?
For home or do-it-yourself electrolytic de-rusting of steel or iron objects, the use of a soda-based electrolyte, such as "washing soda" (sodium carbonate) is almost always mentioned.
I have experimented with both washing soda and "cleaning vinegar" (10% acetic acid) and have found that I get a better result with the vinegar.  Using a voltage or current-controlled power supply to drive from 3 to 10 amps at 5 to 15 volts.  (I believe the vinegar is more conductive).
I'm asking for a chemistry-based answer as to what electrolyte (acetic acid or sodium carbonate) would or should work better to remove surface rust from steel or iron objects.

Vinegar can do it even without the current, but also damage iron itself. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/163641/do-i-need-to-neutralise-iron-steel-metal-with-a-base-after-removing-rust-with

Oxalic acid is also an effective rust remover, but not as  safe as vinegar. In either case, the acid will attack the plain iron, as well as rust, to some extent.

Oxalic acid is somewhat impractical to purchase (for me anyways) and expensive ($50 per lb).  Note that my question pertains to the use of electrolysis, not just the passive action of leaving a rusted object sitting in a bucket of acid.

Well, if it's supposed to be electrolysis, not de-rusting with acid, then it seems logical to use electrolyte which isn't acidic.

Iron and steel don't rust when placed in acid.  They rust after they've been removed and washed or exposed to air / moisture / humidity.  If the acid is strong, then the iron/steel will be eaten away or become pitted, but I think not if electrolysis is used.
